# Rails: get hoverover popup in form

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails-3, popup

i am looking for implementing hoverover pop up function in the form. I got similar question with answer on stackoverflow. When i implemented it, it is not working. Here is the my code:

HTML:

```
<div id='user'><%= f.label :product_code, "Product code", :id => "field2" %></div>
<div id='popup'>(Your name, product and city  initials without space. e.g. MHRRJP or MHRRJP etc for MoungHalwa by Rima Ravi Jain, Pune)</div>
```

CSS:

```
#popup {
height: 50px;
width: 200px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align:middle;
background-color: cornflowerblue;
color: white;
display: none;
padding-top: 8px;
position: absolute;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#user').hover(function() {
    $('#popup').show();
}, function() {
    $('#popup').hide();
});
});
```

This is not working. Can anybody tell where is the error?

Comment: Any more details... any error messages? is anything happening?

Comment: @DickieBoy no error messages. It displays as if no pop-up function written. It just gives hover hand on ProductCode and nothing pops-up. Checked in jsfiddle, working there but on in code.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Javascript to listen for the hover event on `field2` :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#field2').hover(function() {
            $('#popup').show();
        }, function() {
        $('#popup').hide();
    });
});
```